# Set a background picture to a DIV that changes based on screen size

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am trying to get a hero image on a website. I would like the hero image to switch between a mobile and full image version, so I decided to go with background-image instead of 
I can't get the image to show up.

HTML

```
<section class="hero">
    <div class="">Random CTA</div>
    <div class="heroImage"></div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.heroImage {     
background-image: url("/img/heroImageMobile.png") no-repeat center top;     
background-size: cover;     
height: 1200px;     
width: 800px; 
}
```

Eventually, this would be my media query, but I currently have it commented out

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 640px) {
    .heroImage {
    background-image: url("img/heroImageFull.png") no-repeat center top;
    }
```

I have Google this and followed the suggestions on other posts:

- I have added height and width to match the image.
- I have let VS Code fill in the path, so it looks correct. I tried img/filename, /img/filename, and ../img/filename
- I tried with both PNG and JPG file

What am I missing?

Comment: It's often a good idea to use your browser devtools inspect facility to see exactly what CSS is being applied. In this case you should see that backgrond-image value is not valid (I think you meant background which does take the other parameters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use the `background` property instead of `background-image` property which is more specific

`background-image` property only take the url path as value, not all properties

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aeqgwjut/)

**See these resources**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background

Comment: Thank you, that's interesting. Why would background-image not work? My two images have different sizes (800x1200 for mobile, 1920x1200 for desktop), so when I use background the mobile one is fine, but the desktop one is cut off in width.

Comment: I think it's cut off because of the fixed width you have set. you can use max-width instead or fluid width in percentage for media queries.

I updated the fiddle with other css properties so you can see the difference : https://jsfiddle.net/kbcxydjz/

Answer (score 0):

if you want a different image size for each screen size or different images, use the HTML picture tag. This is useful for the image to change at any given size.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_picture.asp

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to position and repeat, you do that individually from setting the background-image property.

```
 .heroImage {     
background-image:url("/img/heroImageMobile.png"); 
background-repeat: no-repeat;    
background-position: center top;
background-size: cover;     
height: 1200px;     
width: 800px; 
}
```

This should fix the issue.